# Hibernate pagination : ScrollableResult vs. setMaxResult() + setFirstResult()

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been using ORM frameworks for a while but I am rather new to Hibernate, though.

Suppose you have a query (is it a Query or a Criteria, does not matter) that retrieves a great result set and that you want to paginate though it. Would you rather use the setMaxResult() and setFirstResult() methods combo, or a ScrollableResult?

Which is the best approach regarding the performances (execution time AND memory consumption)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are implementing a Web application that serves separate pages of results in separate request-response cycles, then there's no way you can use `ScrollableResult` to any advantage. Use setFirst/Max/Result. However, this can be a real performance killer, depending on the exact query and the total size of the result. Especially if the poor db must sort the whole result set every time so it can calculate what are the 100-110th records.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same questions the other day, and settled for `setMaxResult(..)` and `setFirstResult(..)`. The problems are two:

- `ScrollableResult` may execute one query for each call to `next()` if your jdbc driver or database are not handling it properly. This was the case with us (MySQL)
- it is hibernate-specific, rather than JPA standard.

Comment: ScrollableResult does no such thing (on any decent database, that is), it's actually quite performant. It maps quite directly to JDBC's scrolling support, and that maps to native db cursors. Maybe your experience comes from working with a db that doesn't support cursors? Then it would definitely be sheer disaster.

Comment: hmm, probably the mysql jdbc driver isn't handling it properly